# sorting date column in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
Date           Temp_value
01.03.2020       100
09.03.2020       10
05.03.2020       111
08.03.2020       112
31.12.2019       135
```

The date column is not sorted.

I want to sort it in an ascending order for further processing

Code I used that didnot work:

```
df[order(as.Date(df$date, format="%d.%m.%Y")),]
```

Can anyone help me with an alternative

Comment: That is because you are using `df$date` which is `NULL` instead of `df$Date`.  try `df[order(as.Date(df$Date, format="%d.%m.%Y")),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, format="%d.%m.%Y")
df= arrange(df,Date)
```